# Apache Pig convert tuples to multiple rows

Tags: hadoop, tuples, apache-pig

I have a relation with tuples as follows

```
((x1,x2),(10,20)) 
((x3,x4),(30,40))
```

I need to convert the above relation as follows and store in a file

```
x1  10
x2  20
x3  30
x4  40
```

Please note that the number of elements in the inner tuples can vary, but on the outer tuple, its the same i.e.

```
((x1,x2,...,xn),(i1,i2,...,in))
((y1,y2,...,ym),(j1,j2,...,jm))
```

For example,

```
((ab,cd,ef,gh),(1,2,3,4))
((ij,kl,mn),(5,6,7))
```

In this case, it has to be converted as follows

```
ab 1
cd 2
ef 3
gh 4
ij 5
kl 6
mn 7
```

Comment: I believe this is tough to achieve (with variable number of fields within tuples). You will have to write  a UDF to get this done. I will be curious to know the answer. If you get it solved, please update the answer.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884651/pig-latin-split-columns-to-rows) might help